# How do I get a list of popular posts by views?

Tags: php, popular-posts, plugin-jetpack

I am using the Jetpack plugin to get 'site stats' which shows the number of views for blog posts/pages. So I'm no expert or anything but I'm guessing there is a table that stores these views. Is there a way to manipulate this data to create a simple list of the most popular posts by views in the sidebar?

Currently, I'm using a plugin for this but I'd prefer to hard code it straight into the theme.

Any guidance would be massively appreciated.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at the wordpress.com popular posts plugin? I use that plugin to be able to code into my template where to show posts by popularity. Take a peek at the plugin code and maybe you can just grab what you need?

Answer (score 1):

Personaly i already used the [wp-postviews](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postviews/) plugin and it works fine. Comes with a widget to display the list in a sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

Although `wp-postviews` (suggested by `kevin`) is a good plugin, I would definitely recommend the use of [post-views](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-views/) since it offers some usable functions so you can hardcore it right into your theme.

Answer (score 0):

The [WordPress.com Popular Posts plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpresscom-popular-posts/) appears to be working well with Jetpack for me.  I've customized a theme-specific "popular posts" widget ([in Delicate News from ElegantThemes.com](http://www.elegantthemes.com/demo/?theme=DelicateNews)) that was using comments to indicate popular posts using the WPPP_show_popular_posts function that comes with the plugin.  You can check out the code at this link http://pastebin.com/s2PFrWEN .